# Combination of Three.js and CSS3 for animation with 3D objects

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d, css-animations

I have this project to complete- Modeling 3D Lego elements and gather them in the sensible figure using animation. So far I have made the elements via Blender and I can export the as .obj/mlt files, no problems. But for the animation, my project leader told me I could use CSS because would be easier. Till the moment I did not find a way to visualize the ready 3D element in the browser, so I resorted to using `three.js` library and JS code in my index.html file. I managed to a visualized single element in the browser, but the problem is that: How should I continue with CSS and it is possible to take

```
function init() {
        container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);
```

that container or div element and apply CSS 3D transformations and animation to it. I prefer CSS than the JavaScript but if there is no other option I will continue using JavaScrip. 
I appreciate your advice in advance!

Comment: Three.js has a renderer that takes flat HTML elements and animates them in 3D space: https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html but they have to be flat objects. If you want to use Three.js full capabilities, I recommend you start with this intro: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene Either way, it's impossible to make a three.js scene without using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to apply CSS transformations to three.js. This is because CSS changes styles of the DOM elements while three.js animations change properties of objects rendered inside DOM element (canvas). You can probably find animations that fit your project here https://threejs.org/examples/ just look at the source code.